# Скачать файл с http сервера | C++

Tags: c++, winapi

Как скачать файл с http или https сервера, без использования сторонних библиотек?

Comment: Вы это имеете в виду? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Спасибо , но возникла следующая ошибка - "Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _URLDownloadToFileA@20 в функции _main 
"